Setting up Query in init causes app to freeze
I'm trying to filter results to get all characters that are associated with a story. When navigating to the view it filters as it should, but as soon as you select the Add Character option, the app just freezes.
I've found that if I comment out the Query line in the init, and filter out as part of the foreach I don't get the freeze.
Can anyone advise how I should be doing these predicates as it seems init isn't the best place to do it
The views code is
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct CharacterListView: View {
    let story : Story
    @Query(sort: \Character.name, order: .forward) private var characters: [Character]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(characters) { char in
                CharacterListCellView(char: char)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                NavigationLink(destination: CharacterAddView(story: story)) {
                    Label("Add Character", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Characters", displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
    init(story: Story) {
        self.story = story
        
        let id = story.persistentModelID
        let predicate = #Predicate<Character> { char in
            char.story?.persistentModelID == id
        }
        
        _characters = Query(filter: predicate, sort: [SortDescriptor(\.name)] )
    }
}


I've narrowed it down to a line in the AddCharacterView file
struct CharacterAddView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    let story : Story
    
    // Character details
    @State private var characterName: String = ""
    
    // Images
    @State private var showImageMenu = false;
    @State private var isShowPhotoLibrary = false
    @State private var isShowCamera = false
    //@State private var image = UIImage() <-- This line
    
    @State private var imageChanged = false
    
    @State private var isSaving : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {

    }
}

If I do either of the below it works
If I comment out the UIImage variable then I don't get the freeze, but I can't update the image variable
If I comment out the query in init, then it works but doesn't filter and I have to do it as part of the foreach

If the app freezes when you select the toolbar item then the init has already been executed so maybe more interesting is what happens in CharacterAddView

It seems to be related to @State private var image = UIImage() in the CharacterAddView, as if I comment out that line it works fine
